# Tests for comparing ratio data from independent samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, ratio

The data are from an international study comparing participants' perceptions of how much more corporate CEOs make compared to unskilled workers (median ratios are used because mean ratios did not pass normality tests).

For example, participants in Russia (N = 1200) estimated that CEOs make 33.4 times as much as workers, where as US participants (N = 1800) judged that CEOs make 27.1 times as much as workers.

How can I test whether the ratio estimates of Russian and US participants differ significiantly? Also - there are estimates from 29 countries. How do I handle so many individual comparisons?